# jQuery script not running after an include

Tags: jquery, dom, include

In my `index.html` I have:

```
<head>
...
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "include/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "include/js/jquery.inc-7.js"></script
</head>
```

Which loads jquery and a little [include script](http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/inc-a-super-tiny-client-side-include-javascript-jquery-plugin.html), both are properly loaded and working.

Then comes the body with the special div class "inc:*" which is recognized by the plugin and includes the file specified inside it:

```
<body>
<div class="inc:include/header.html"></div>
...
...
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "include/js/prd-jquery.js"></script>
</body>
```

At the end of the body I load another script which is meant to manipulate the `header.html` to hide\show nested menus on click. And before you say it even if the script contains the `.click` method, I've already read a lot of other similar question which all ends with substituting the `.click` with `.on('click', function etc)`. Either ways don't work however..

Why the prd-jquery isn't properly working and the clicks on the menu are not recognized?

[Here](https://github.com/Maxiride/test) is a little setup for example and the prd-jquery.js file.

Comment: Check the console if there is any error.

Comment: did you add the $(document).ready() listener?

Comment: No errors are reported, for now I found a little workaround adding at the end of the body (but inside it):
`<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$.getScript('include/js/prd-jquery.js');
});
</script>`
this seems to solve the issue.

Comment: @AlvinMagalona we posted at the same time, yeah the .ready() did his job =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very silly silly error, still got a lot to learn.
On the other hand I have to say that in all the answers I found this aspect wasn't mentioned and since I'm still learning I didn't figured it our myself.

A damn `$(document).ready()` before **everything** was just the solution =)

Issue solved, I hope no more weird errors pop around xD